# Get element from list of list in lisp

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I am a beginner with lisp.
I manipulate list of list:
((name1, second) (name2, second2))

The goal of my function is to get the second element of the list that have name as it first node.

For example:
my list is: ((name1, second1) (name2, second2))
getelement list name1 should return second1.

```
(defun getelement (list name)
  (if (eq list '())
    (if (string= (caar list) name)
      (car (car (cdr list)))
      (getelement (cdr list) name)
    )
    ()
  )
)
```

But I get this error. I really don't understand what is happening with my code. I tried to put ' before expressions...

```
Error: The variable LIST is unbound.
Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging
Error signalled by IF.
Backtrace: IF
```

Comment: @Bill Sorry, I changed the names of the variables but forgot about this one. nodelist is  list (the argument).

Comment: Does it give the error message when you use the correct variable names? If so: using what lisp, and how do you call your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (defun get-element (list name)
    (cadr (assoc name list :test #'string=)))
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The if clauses are in the wrong order.
2. When the string matches, you are taking the next element (cdr) instead of that matching element (car)

This should work:

```
(defun getelement (list name)
     (if (eq list '()) ;end of list,...
         '() ;return empty list
         (if (string= (caar list) name) ;matches,
             (car (car list))  ;take the matching element
             (getelement (cdr list) name))))
```

Comment: The function should return the element _following_ the matched element, i.e. `(car (cdr (car list)))`, or better `(second (first list))`.